# JavaScript scroll horizontally inside a container is not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am using Vanilla JS to create a slider npm package such as slick.js. I am running into this particular problem when I want to scroll horizontally inside of a container. I am able to scroll to the right on the first click, but when I click my button to scroll more than once, It will automatically scroll to the last div inside of my container. I only want to use vanilla js to build this slider.

I have 4 divs inside of my container that are background-images that take up the entire width. I want to scroll to the next div inside of my container when I click the left or right button.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('click');
const right = document.getElementById('right');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.scrollLeft += '1133';
});
```

```html
<body>


    <div class="slick1 presentation-container mx-auto mt-5 " id="presentation" style="position: relative;">

        <div data-slide="1"
            style="background-image: url('https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg'); height: 600px">

        </div>
        <div data-slide="2"
            style="background-image: url('https://miro.medium.com/max/5000/1*jFyawcsqoYctkTuZg6wQ1A.jpeg'); height: 600px">

        </div>
        <div data-slide="3"
            style="background-image: url('https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg'); height: 600px">

        </div>
        <div data-slide="4"
            style="background-image: url('https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rare-combinaties.jpg'); height: 600px">

        </div>

    </div>

    <button id='click'>left</button>






    <script src="build/bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
        presentation.start('presentation')
    </script>


</body>
```

[image]

Here is the entire bundle

```
var presentation = (function (exports) {
  'use strict';

  function htmlToElement(html) {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    html = html.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.firstChild;
  }

  const forward = htmlToElement(`<div class="presentation-forward-arrow-container">
<svg class="presentation-navigation presentation-forward" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
        d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-8.707l-3-3a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414L10.586 9H7a1 1 0 100 2h3.586l-1.293 1.293a1 1 0 101.414 1.414l3-3a1 1 0 000-1.414z"
        clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
</div>`);

  const backward = htmlToElement(`<div class="presentation-back-arrow-container">
<svg class="presentation-navigation presentation-back" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd"
        d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm.707-10.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 000 1.414l3 3a1 1 0 001.414-1.414L9.414 11H13a1 1 0 100-2H9.414l1.293-1.293z"
        clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
</svg>
</div>`);

  let container = undefined;
  const slides = [];

  const button = document.getElementById('click');

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('click');
    container.scrollLeft += '1150';
    //   slides[0].classList.add('slidein');
  });

  function build(id) {
    container = document.getElementById(id);

    addSlidesToArray();
    addNavigation();
  }

  const addSlidesToArray = () => {
    container.childNodes.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.dataset !== undefined) {
        if (el.dataset.slide) {
          slides.push(el);
          el.classList.add('container-child');
        }
      }
    });
  };

  const addNavigation = () => {
    slides.forEach((x) => {
      x.appendChild(forward.cloneNode(true));
      x.appendChild(backward.cloneNode(true));
    });
  };

  function validateID(id) {
    const container = document.getElementById(id);
    if (container && container !== undefined) {
      return true;
    } else {
      console.error('Presentation requires a valid ID');
      return false;
    }
  }

  function start(id) {
    if (!validateID(id)) {
      return false;
    }

    build(id);
  }

  exports.start = start;

  Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

  return exports;
})({});
```

Comment: Is it possible to include the `presentation` object (particularly the `.start` method) in your code sample so the snippet will run and we can see the same behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Yes, I just added it

Comment: The snippet still isn't running. It's okay, someone should be able to provide an answer.

Comment: (BTW, this public-domain vanilla JS carousel exists in case it's helpful: https://zoltantothcom.github.io/vanilla-js-carousel/)